# After updating grub2, my system will not find windows on another HD. Can someone help me figure out how to make the grub entry correctly?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I have looked at several forums, but I have had trouble figuring out the right steps to fix the issue.  I updated grub and it will not see the os on my ssd. OS-prober does not return any values.  I assume that it only searches the drive that it is intalled on.  I used boot-repair to no avail, except for this handy link with a lot of system info.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QzzKhGYm4v/
I have Ubuntu running on one HD and windows 10 on a separate drive.  The windows 10 install is on this drive /dev/nvme0n1.  boot-repair says I can use gparted to make a boot partition, but I am reluctant to do so without guidance from the community.  I have messed this process up in the past.  The BIOS does not give me an option to boot into my other drive either.  I installed grub customizer and I when I make a new entry for the windows disk using chainloader, the program tells me there is an error building boot sequence. Check parameters! If I need to share more information I can.  Can I make an entry into the grub config file that will allow me to boot the os on the nvme0n1 drive?  Do I need grub installed on that drive?
nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 10
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 562163E0-FD70-40C3-9C8E-C0AFA1087225
          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1  2048 2000408575 2000406528 953.9G Microsoft basic data

nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8:;
1:1049kB:1024GB:1024GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;

nvme0n1
└─nvme0n1p1 ntfs     C6646B80646B71DB                     f6235d4c-ff7a-4fbc-beb2-4c92895d7308          Basic data partition

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.